# How should I bridge a JAXB class and a POJO (domain object) used by a DAO?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I want to use the same class as a JAXB class and a domain object for a DAO.  This way I can easily move data back and forth from incoming/outgoing XML web service calls to direct CRUD transactions on a database.  Is there a design pattern out there that I could use?  I am leaning towards AbstractFactory because I have some database util functions that prep the SQL parameters without having to know the table/column names.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "labdata")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "labdata", propOrder = {"labId",
                                        "labDesc",
                                        "lastUpdateDatetime",
                                        "userId"})
public class LabData extends DbObject
{

    @XmlTransient
    private HashMap<String, Object> mappedFields;

    @XmlElement(name="lab_id", required = true)
    private Integer labId;

    @XmlElement(name="lab_desc", required = true)
    private String labDesc;

    @XmlElement(name="last_altered_dt", required = true)
    private Timestamp lastUpdateDatetime;

    @XmlElement(name="user_id", required = true)
    private String userId;

    @XmlTransient
    private final String labIdField = "TST_LAB_CD";

    @XmlTransient
    private final String labDescField = "LAB_DSC_TE";

    @XmlTransient
    private final String lastUpdateDatetimeField = "INS_GMT_TS";

    @XmlTransient
    private final String userIdField = "USR_ID";

    @XmlTransient
    private final String tableName = "TSTLAB";

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public LabData() {
        super();
        mappedFields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor which takes all fields as parameters 
     * and will update the protected hash map after setting all the fields.
     * @param labId {@link Integer}
     * @param labDesc {@link String}
     * @param lastUpdateDatetime {@link Timestamp}
     * @param userId {@link String}
     */
    public LabData(Integer labId, String labDesc, Timestamp lastUpdateDatetime, String userId) {
        super();
        this.labId = labId;
        this.labDesc = labDesc;
        this.lastUpdateDatetime = lastUpdateDatetime;
        this.userId = userId;
        updateHashMap();
    }

    public Object[] getFieldValues() {
        return new Object[] {this.labId, this.labDesc, this.lastUpdateDatetime, this.userId};
    }

    public Object[] getUpdateFieldValues() {
        return new Object[] {this.labDesc, this.lastUpdateDatetime, this.userId};
    }

    public void updateHashMap() {
        mappedFields.clear();
        mappedFields.put(this.labIdField, this.labId);
        mappedFields.put(this.labDescField, this.labDesc);
        mappedFields.put(this.lastUpdateDatetimeField, this.lastUpdateDatetime);
        mappedFields.put(this.userIdField, this.userId);
    }

    getters and setters...
}
```

Database Util:

```
public List<Object[]> createInsertBatchArgs(DbObject[] dbPojos){
    List<Object[]> args = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(DbObject dbPojo: dbPojos) {
        args.add(dbPojo.getFieldValues());
    }
    return args;
}

public List<Object[]> createUpdateBatchArgs(DbObject[] dbPojos, String... updateFields){
    List<Object[]> args = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(DbObject dbPojo: dbPojos) {
        Object[] fields = dbPojo.getUpdateFieldValues();
        Object[] values = Arrays.copyOf(fields, fields.length+updateFields.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < updateFields.length; i++) {
            values[values.length-updateFields.length+i] = 
                      dbPojo.getFieldValue(updateFields[i]);
        }
        args.add(values);
    }
    return args;
}

public List<Object[]> createDeleteBatchArgs(DbObject[] dbPojos, String... deleteFieldName){
    List<Object[]> args = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] values = new Object[deleteFieldName.length];
    for(DbObject dbPojo: dbPojos) {
        for(int i = 0; i < deleteFieldName.length; i++) {
            values[i] = dbPojo.getFieldValue(deleteFieldName[i]);
        }
        args.add(values);
    }
    return args;
}
```

If I remove the DbObject inheritance then the usage of the DAO methods by casting causes  java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack.  Unfortunately I don't have the ability to implement a new framework that would easily do this.

Comment: Mixing your DAO and your DTO (Data Transfer Object, aka your JAXB classes here) is not somehting you would usually want. It's better to separate those things most of the time. And if the content is the same, you can do automatic mapping between DAO and DTO with tools like Dozer instead of writing boring lines of code.

Comment: Yea I definitely assumed it was not something I wanted to do however  I wanted to try to bypass writing boring lines of code as you stated.  I will check out Dozer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be an answer outside of separating the two layers.  I used [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to map the JAXB and pojos to each other.  This framework also also has an implementation of direct JAXB bean mapping to pojos.